# Remove Calendar Control from RadGrid Filter menu

Tags: asp.net, telerik, telerik-grid, radgrid, rad-controls

Is it possible to force the RadGrid to use only the filtering textbox. without calendar control appear in the filtering menu for a datetime column?

[image]

My RadGrid has auto generated columns and i have encounter some problems with this date column.
I posted them on telerik forum but no response yet.

http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/grid/filter-options-not-showing-up-when-binding-a-datetime-column.aspx

http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/grid/radgrid-column-widths-and-date-picker.aspx

so i just want to use a textbox filter for the date column as other string columns.

Comment: what about using `  <FilterTemplate>` in your `GridColumn` ?

Comment: @zey Grid has auto generated columns.so i'm not able to use FilterTemplate